# Date / Time Model Binder

Tags: datetime, modelbinder

I already followed every step in the following tutorial but got some problem. My purpose is to use model binder to bind date and time and then save in a datetime field. 
http://devblog.lundy.us/2010/09/28/date-time-picker-asp-net-mvc-jquery-part-1/

I just have a quick question: **How can he implement the following code in the edit view?**

```
"<%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.Start.Date)%>"
```

How did he get `Start.Date`?
Because he only has `Start` and `End` in his model. Where did he define variable `Date`?

And I got an error when I implement above code:
'System.Nullable' doesn't contain a definition for 'Date'

I'm sure I have exactly the same Model and DateTimeModelBinder.cs as his code.

Please tell me why I can't use `model => model.Start.Date`
Or tell me any tutorial explicitly teach me how to bind date and time.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DateTime` data type in .NET exposes some properties, such as `.Date` (the same date value, but with time set to 12am), `.TimeOfDay`, `.Year`, etc.  The example blog post you're referring to uses `DateTime`, thus all of these properties are available. Also note that `DateTime` is a value type and cannot be `null`.

Your model, on the other hand, uses a property of type `DateTime?` which is a reference type and can be `null`. Nullable types are reference type wrappers around value types. All of them expose a property called `.HasValue` of type `bool`, and a property `.Value` of the type that the wrapping nullable type corresponds to. In case of `DateTime?`, the type of the `.Value` property is `DateTime`.

With your model the following should work:

`<%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.Start.Value.Date)%>`

Comment: Thanks! As you said, DateTime is a value type which can't be null. This solved my problem.